# Why this sample code has an possible Null Pointer Access?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Why this code has an possible Null Pointer Access?

```
    Object v = (RuntimeException) null;
    throw (RuntimeException) v;
```

and why this is not?

```
    throw (RuntimeException) null;
```

Comment: sry, i corrected the question

Comment: How did you determine that the one code has a possible Null Pointer Access (what's that anyway?) and the other one has not?

Comment: it is an 'error' in eclipse IDE, is it a eclipse bug or are the statements different in java ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Object v = (RuntimeException) null;
throw (RuntimeException) v;
```

[Compiles fine](http://ideone.com/cBMF4)

---

**Update** upon complete change in Question

Both of them will throw NPE